# On application start receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent

I would like to make a receiver that is called each time a new application is started.
I see that the ActivityManager[0] allow me to see all the running applications, but I'd like to avoid polling it.
How can I do it (if I can)?

[0] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I do it (if I can)?

You can't. There are no broadcast `Intent`s for such events.